# "Why don't you" vs. "Why won't you" in suggestions and questions

Tags: tense, questions

What is the difference between,

> Why don't you decorate the house yourself?
>
> Why won't you decorate the house yourself?

Are both of these sentences grammatically correct?

And what changes when we are not making a suggestion to somebody directly but speak about something in 3rd person, i.e.,

> What doesn't/won't Cameroon intervene?
>
> What doesn't/won't she marry?
>
> Why don't/won't these people leave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually these examples illustrate a subtle but important distinction between what you *want* to do, and what you actually *do*.  The use of *will not/won't* emphasizes the personal choice behind the action, rather than the action itself.  Example:

> I don't eat candy (I make a habit of not eating candy)
>
> I won't eat candy (I make the *choice* not to eat candy)

Sometimes this distinction is trivial, but not always.  For example:

> Alan:  Did you hear what our governor did yesterday?
>   Brian:  No.  I **don't** watch the news.
>   A:  You don't watch the news, or you **won't** watch the news?
>   B:  I try to avoid it, as almost every story these days just makes me upset.

Here Alan is asking Brian to clarify whether he simply doesn't make the effort to watch the news, or he actively chooses *not* to watch the news.

It's similar when talking about a third person, again emphasizing the distinction between what they *do* and what they *choose* to do.

> Why don't they get married (I don't understand the reason why they have not done this)
>
> Why won't they get married (I don't understand the reason why they *choose* not to do this)

Keep in mind that the "why don't ..." structure can be also used as a polite suggestion, so you have to be careful to understand the meaning from context.  Examples:

> **Why don't you** take a nap?  You look tired.
>
> **Why don't they** get married?  We can have the minister out here in an hour, and my mother would be happy to cook up a celebratory dinner.

"Why won't you ..." is not really a suggestion.  It's more of an *assertion* as it presumes you have made the decision not to do that thing.

> A: **Why wont you** go out with him?  He seems like a nice person.
>   B:  It's not that I won't go out with him.  It's just that lately I've been too busy.

Comment: So to use "Why won't you..." as a suggestion is wrong? I feel inclined to say "why won't you..." to make a suggestion; however, today I read in a grammar book that "why don't you..." is used to make suggestions.

Comment: Why won't you eat candy? means: Why have you made the choice not to eat candy. He explained it for the declarative but it can be interrogative, too.